# Ios make label wrap content both height and width like android

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios how to make label as wrap content both width and height.
i have use following things too

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

But i cant make label height and width as wrap content

Comment: have you tried sizeThatFits ??

Comment: have you taken a look at NSLayoutConstriants?

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you use Auto Layout, you can always use this line to make the label fit its content horizontally

```
[textLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired
                             forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

If you are not using Auto Layout, try adding this after setting the font, font size and all other details.

```
[textLabel sizeToFit]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
[textLabel sizeToFit];
```

after:

```
textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Also, if you are using "Auto" layout, then check your constraints are not conflicting. Make sure if you have not provided "Fixed" width constraint.